# I've bought a DIE without a tap

Tags: mechanical-engineering

So I bought a lovely cheap second hand die to create wooden threads on ebay it cuts:

If i measure in metric

- it taps a 38mm diameter at a 6mm pitch

OR

if I measure it in Imperial it appears to tap 1 1/12 inch diameter @
4 TPI

The only marking I have on it is "38 x 6" and I purchased it in Denmark so I'm assuming it's a M38x6 die.

Now the twist is that standard bolts tend to skip from M36 to M40 and not at that pitch., again I know I'm an idiot :)

So I have 2 questions:

1. Does anyone have a M38x6 tap they want to sell??
2. Does anyone know of any local machine shops to ireland that I can
   contact?
3. Is anyone an amateur machinist do you fancy taking this on??

My google fu has failed me, and I can't find the right bolt :(

Comment: Shopping questions and product recommendations are off topic here, unfortunately, of which all three of your requests firmly fall into.

Comment: Sadly @DKNguyen is right - this question is a little off-topic for the fairly strict StackExchange format. If you rephrased your question as a more general one about thread standards, you'd get the answer you already know - that 38mmx6mm is not a standard size.

Comment: Since you are cutting wood, then hardened steel etc. isn't a requirement. I fall into the 3) category, and am in Wales, so not a million miles away. You could ask in https://www.reddit.com/r/machining/ to see if you can find someone more local?

Comment: https://www.metricmcc.com/103tr-high-speed-steel-trapezoidal-tap-p-28442.html This was the best I could find - but it's RFQ only, so they'd be making it to order, too... Is your Die Trapezoidal or standard 60degree 'triangles'?

Comment: what is is you need, bolts or nuts?  Any machinist can make custom threaded bolts or rods, but you already have a die to do that.  Making a tap that can cut wood should also be in the wheelhouse of any machinist.